# Is there a designated place to store helper scripts in a Laravel app?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel app that uses a small Node utility to process data and then store that output in the standard Laravel `/storage` directory. From Laravel, the utility is called using the `symfony/process` component, and the console output tells my app what to do next.

Right now, I've got the utility stored in a directory I created called `/scripts`, but I'm curious to know if there's a better or more standardized place to store such utilities or even shell scripts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A common practice that I've seen is to have a `bin` directory.

Comment: This is a good consideration. It falls in-line with a lot of other app structures, too.